# Upload Speed is 60 kB/s in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7

I have written a client code in Java to upload files to one of our servers. In Ubuntu machine, the client is able to upload files to Server at the rate of 5 MB/s. However in Windows 7, the upload happens only at the rate of 60 kB/s (Anti-Virus & Firewall disabled).

The code snippet is as follows:

```
.......................

URL server = new URL(url);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)server.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("content-length",fsize);
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("file-name", file.getName());
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int)file.length());
connection.setReadTimeout(30000);

if (file.exists()) {
    connection.connect();

    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
    byte []buf = new byte[256*1024];
    int length=0;
    try {
    while ((length=in.read(buf))!=-1) {
        out.write(buf, 0,length);
    }
    out.flush();
}
..............
```

Please let me know whether I need to add any HTTP headers (or) I should make any change in my code.

regards,
kit_kings

Comment: how do you know that the upload is only 60kB/s on the windows machine?

Comment: Using C / libcurl some years ago we found that there is some value for a buffer size in both Windows and Linux that you could set when creating a connection. The default value for Windows was the same as in Windows 3.11 and very low (8k IIRC), while for Linux it had been updated to 64K (IIRC). Changing it in Windows did provide a significant increase in the connection speed and brought it almost to Linux speeds. Unfortunately I don't recall the name of that value, but it might be worth investigating.

Comment: Can you check you can upload faster than this in some other program like IE or using http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: @Aaron: The code for printing the time between each write was removed from above snippet. The server is asynchronous, so the writes are non-blocking writes.

Comment: @SHuan76: I believe you meant the byte array limit. I changed its value  to  [16 * 1024], the upload happens in 115 kB/s

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Speedtest.net says my upload speed is 47 Mbps